# Firefox webdriver throws Insecure Connection error

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

My developer has changed the URL from Http to Https, from then my Firefox Webdriver script throws Insecure connection error. How do I confirm exception and then proceed with my test?

Comment: If you visit the URL manually, does it ask you to accept the insecure certificate?

Comment: No. i have manually accepted the certificate.

Comment: You say no, but then say you did what I asked?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If I visit the URL manually I don't get the insecure certificate as I have manually accepted the certificate before. Hope I am clear now.