# HTML CSS: href not working despite using "https://"

Tags: html, css

Currently making a draft-version of my website by only using HTML and CSS. I'm facing a problem where the href is not working, although I am using the "https://" with the href attribute.

When I clicked on the link, it first shows the local host, and then the actual link to an online website. When I tried it in code pen, the link of code pen came before the actual link I wanted to use (EX: https://s.codepen.io/boomerang/007058b4cabfb2d31cc9b505906c23171484485046569/%E2%80%9Dhttps://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp%E2%80%9D).

Why?

Image of the part I am having trouble with:

[image: Image of the part I am having trouble with]

Comment: Could you add a snippet on JSFiddle or a JSBin for us to take a look at?

Comment: Here is a link to the code http://codepen.io/Ruuu/#

Answer (score 0):

It seems you or your text editor has inserted the wrong kind of quote character. In your codepen the links are using this: `”` (A unicode right double quotation mark) whereas they should be using this: `"` (A unicode quotation mark). This is causing the links to be invalid.

Comment: I faced anothe problem. Can you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41163855/7421429 ?